# Styling user controls in UWP class library and overwrite it in consuming app

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, styles

Imagine a UWP class library containing several user controls with custom logic. The custom controls may be open sourced and people can create their own apps with it.

```
-Controls
---MyTextBox
---MyButton
---and so on
```

A default styling of these user controls can be done with explicit styles inline in the xaml of the user control. I tested that. But its not very flexible. People might want to apply their own styles to it.

Wanted to get more sophisticated an created a couple of ResourceDictionaries. Lets say to simplify it:

```
-Styles
--MyTextBoxDictionary.xaml
--MyButtonDictionary.xaml
```

For the time being these are just files. Not known to anything. If I want to use them, I learned here on stackoverflow, I would need to have a file "Themes/Generic.xaml" (remember I am in a UWP class library project and need to keep this pre-requisite).
Learned here, that I would need to load the dictionaries in that file with MergedDictionaries like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MyTextBoxDictionary.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MyButtonDictionary.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Because my dictionaries to be loaded are in a folder called "Styles" I would need to do something like [PACK URIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/aa970069(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for the same assembly just from a different folder.
Did not work. Buttons still no style.
So I moved the style definitions directly into the "Themes/Generic.xaml" just for testing.
Did not work. Buttons still no style.

So a couple of questions:

1. How can I use multiple dictionary files in a class library project located in a separate folder to style my custom user controls?
2. If above is not possible, which other ways do I have?
3. Is this even possible with ThemedStyles?
4. How can I let a consuming app overwrite my "default" styles? Isnt the only way that I use implicit styling for the default styling and explicit for the overwriting style? Any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a ResourceDictionary to your Themes/Generic.xaml file like such

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject.Name/Styles/MyTextBoxDictionary.xaml" />
```

Rather than having to know the exact syntax you can use the Propertoies pane to set the Source. To accomplish this you can enter the following

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Click inside the ResourceDictionary, then in the Properties window select the source you would like
[image]

Comment: First of all thank you and sorry for responding so late (got sick).
Unfortunately that does not work. I mean your proposed way of adding dictionaries technically works, but the control does not get the styling applied.

After reading much more about it it has to do with the fact that we are using user controls and not custom controls and additionally that x:Key tags in a referenced dict from the merged dicts in Generic.xaml wont be picked up. Even the part of overwriting those styles later in some App.xaml is very unclear still.

Comment: USerControls cannot be re-themed. Only custom controls can. You can easily add a new custom control by right clicking the project and select Add -> New Item and then Custom Control (WPF). This will add a new class and style to the Generic.xaml file. Transfer your theme to the Generic.xaml and any code to the new class. It's not a 1 for 1 transfer. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8